# Stopping a network server from accepting further connections

Tags: networking, rust

Currently I do this in order to stop a server from accepting further connections upon external request (e.g. a client sends "shutdown" message):

```rust
let listener = try_err!(TcpListener::bind(addr), "cannot bind: {}");

let (tstreams, rstreams) = channel();
let (tshutdown, rshutdown) = channel();
spawn(proc() {
    let mut acceptor = try_err!(listener.listen(), "cannot listen: {}");

    loop {
        acceptor.set_timeout(Some(100));
        match acceptor.accept() {
            Ok(stream) => tstreams.send(stream),
            Err(ref e) if e.kind == TimedOut => {}
            Err(e) => println!("Failed to accept: {}", e)
        }
        match rshutdown.try_recv() {
            Ok(()) | Err(Disconnected) => break,
            Err(Empty) => {}
        }
    }
});
```

Then I can receive incoming connections through `rstreams` channel and are able to shut down the acceptor loop via `tshutdown` channel.

However, I dislike this approach, especially arbitrary `Some(100)` timeout which seems to be inevitable here. Is it possible to do something better than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a better way to implement this until the whole '[how to do async properly?](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6842)' question is solved.

Comment: That's what I feared... Thanks anyway. I'll accept your answer.